# Resource ID showing instead of string when appending null message at the end

Tags: java, android, string, string-concatenation, null-pointer

In one of my functions I produce a Toast message if there is an error. The message makes a call to a resource ID and fetches the message from the last error. If the last error returns null, then the actual int ID is shown, instead of the dereferenced string.

```java
Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this, 
               (R.string.error_onCanceled + " " mLastError.getMessage()),  
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

> 2131689536 null

```java
Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this,
                (R.string.error_onCanceled),
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

> On Canceled: error =
>   ** this is my string from the resource file

I can't figure out why appending null to the end of the string makes it return the int ID instead of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R.string.error_onCanceled` is an `int`.

There are two forms of `makeText()`. One takes an `int`, treating it as a string resource ID. The other takes a `CharSequence` or `String`.

```
Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this,
            (R.string.error_onCanceled),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This uses the one that takes an `int` and uses your string resource.

For the other, you have `R.string.error_onCanceled + " " mLastError.getMessage()`. This does not compile. I am going to assume that you really mean `R.string.error_onCanceled + " " + mLastError.getMessage()`. In that case, all Java can do is:

- Convert your `int` to a `String`
- Concatenate it with the other strings

But Java converts the `int` to a `String` literally, as Java has no idea about Android string resources.

The most direct way to fix this is to use `getString(R.string.error_onCanceled_) + " " + mLastError.getMessage()`, so you ask Android to give you the string associated with the string resource ID.

Or, you could change the string resource to have a %d in it:

```
<string name="error_onCanceled">** this is my string from the resource file %s</string>
```

Then, you would use `getString(R.string.error_onCanceled, mLastError.getMessage())` to get the combined message to pass to the `Toast`.

One way or another, if you are not passing the plain string resource ID into `makeText()`, you need to use `getString()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do concatenation with the string call the string_element in this way:

```
Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this, 
           (getString(R.string.error_onCanceled) + " " mLastError.getMessage()),  
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare is absolutely right

Toast.makeText is an overloaded method

You can create a toast from a string:

```
/**
 * Make a standard toast that just contains a text view.
 *
 * @param context  The context to use.  Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
 *                 or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
 * @param text     The text to show.  Can be formatted text.
 * @param duration How long to display the message.  Either {@link #LENGTH_SHORT} or
 *                 {@link #LENGTH_LONG}
 *
 */
public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, @Duration int duration) {
    return makeText(context, null, text, duration);
}
```

Or resource Id:

```
/**
 * Make a standard toast that just contains a text view with the text from a resource.
 *
 * @param context  The context to use.  Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
 *                 or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
 * @param resId    The resource id of the string resource to use.  Can be formatted text.
 * @param duration How long to display the message.  Either {@link #LENGTH_SHORT} or
 *                 {@link #LENGTH_LONG}
 *
 * @throws Resources.NotFoundException if the resource can't be found.
 */
public static Toast makeText(Context context, @StringRes int resId, @Duration int duration)
                            throws Resources.NotFoundException {
    return makeText(context, context.getResources().getText(resId), duration);
}
```

You are accidentally mixing them